# Air conditioning window unit

Tags: air-conditioning

My father in-laws wife plugged a brand new air conditioning window unit I with a small extension cord and she said it ran for just a moment and then cut off. And it has not turned on again. Does anyone know what the problem is and can I fix whatever is wrong with it. It's brand new and I sure could use the help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? Different power socket? Checked fuses?

Comment: what's the rating on the extension cord?  Does the air conditioner's own cord have a lump on it with a couple of buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a reset button for the circuit near where the power cord comes out of the air conditioner. Usually a little black or red nub.  Is the outlet still hot? It's possible she tripped the circuit breaker for that outlet.